# Google analytics page tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I have a question about google analytics page tracking. I have a website and the main domain is www.tdconnect.nl. Now I want the following. All pages hanging under tdconnect.nl/cisco/. Should get a separate Google Analytics. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a default GA tag would do the job unless you specifically want to completely independently track the cisco subdirectory. in which case 2 separate tags are required, and you should check outthe following https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#singleSubDirectory

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to show data under `tdconnect.nl/cisco/` in a separate GA account.

1. You may choose to create a new filter against your directory.
   (Recommended).
2. You may create a different GA Account altogether and
   then change the property ID on the new section.
3. You may choose to create a new sub-domain `cisco.tdconnect.nl`